# How to explode column with multiple records into multiple Columns in Spark

Tags: json, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new using Spark and Scala and would like to get some help about this situation:
This is my current schema.

```
 |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- horizon: double (nullable = true)
 |-- risk_table: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- index: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- risk_buy: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- reward_buy: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- risk_sell: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- reward_sell: double (nullable = true)
 |-- symbol_id: string (nullable = true)
```

Here is an example of how looks the data:

```
+--------------------+
|          risk_table|
+--------------------+
|[{count, 201.0, 2...|
|[{count, 219.0, 2...|
|[{count, 119.0, 1...|
|[{count, 217.0, 2...|
|[{count, 17.0, 17...|
|[{count, 189.0, 1...|
|[{count, 105.0, 1...|
|[{count, 188.0, 1...|
|[{count, 111.0, 1...|
|[{count, 276.0, 2...|
|[{count, 70.0, 70...|
|[{count, 121.0, 1...|
|[{count, 133.0, 1...|
|[{count, 116.0, 1...|
|[{count, 70.0, 70...|
|[{count, 193.0, 1...|
|[{count, 131.0, 1...|
|[{count, 93.0, 93...|
|[{count, 84.0, 84...|
|[{count, 114.0, 1...|
+--------------------+
```

I would like to explode *risk_table* column values into multiples columns, usually have 4 nested documents/dictionaries where the index name change, so the expected output would look something like this

```
+-----------+------+---------+------------------+--------------------+-----+---------------------+
| symbol_id | date | index_0 | risk_buy_index_0 | reward_buy_index_0 | ... | reward_sell_index_3 |
+-----------+------+---------+------------------+--------------------+-----+---------------------+
| APPL      | xxxx | 0       | 0                | 0                  | ... | 0                   |
+-----------+------+---------+------------------+--------------------+-----+---------------------+
| APPL      | xxxx | 0       | 0                | 0                  | ... | 0                   |
+-----------+------+---------+------------------+--------------------+-----+---------------------+
| APPL      | xxxx | 0       | 0                | 0                  | ... | 0                   |
+-----------+------+---------+------------------+--------------------+-----+---------------------+
```

I found some information about how to explode only one document/dictionary but not nested, I'll highly appreciate if can someone help with that.

**UPDATE #1**:

After @vilalabinot answer, this is the returned dataframe:

```
|index_0|    risk_buy_index_0|  reward_buy_index_0|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  count|               201.0|               201.0|
|   mean|-0.00842858807942...|0.034462956359400186|
|    std|0.010321886923670486|0.024028309176849814|
|    min|-0.04742597827704211|                -0.0|
|    25%|-0.01445728455890...|0.018636627472515977|
|    50%|-0.00424808836023...|0.029910269192422685|
|    75%|                 0.0| 0.04336544006150825|
|    max|                -0.0|   0.141510207428056|
|  count|               219.0|               219.0|
|   mean|-0.00825181843661...| 0.03181657870541232|
|    std|0.009920846095541787| 0.02024399549501371|
|    min|-0.04707151894023976|0.002521912798573491|
|    25%|-0.01330755207577...|0.015617730900798106|
|    50%|-0.00475774347023...|0.026639344262294966|
|    75%|                -0.0| 0.04315554182360575|
|    max|                -0.0| 0.11667197234981128|
|  count|               119.0|               119.0|
|   mean|-0.01337031203096...|0.049558424443669605|
|    std| 0.01942541767615014|0.036681645417330024|
|    min| -0.0951268206361449|0.004135946772163351|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Instead, I would like to get something like this, where the values of records inside risk_table will be appended as a column rather than rows.

```
+-----------+------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+-------------+
| symbol_id | mean | count | min | max | 50% | 75% | reward_buy | reward_sell |
+-----------+------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+-------------+
|           | ...  | ...   | ... | ... | ... | ... | ....       | ...         |
+-----------+------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+-------------+
| ...       | ...  | ...   | ... | ... | ... | ... | ...        | ...         |
+-----------+------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+-------------+
| ...       | ...  | ...   | ... | ... | ... | ... | ...        | ...         |
+-----------+------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your dataset is `main`. First, we have to explode the content of `risk_table`, since if we don't, we will get arrays as values of columns, which we do not like, so:

```
df1 = df1.withColumn("explode", explode(col("risk_table")))
```

now, `explode` column has one object per row; there are a lot of ways to create columns from objects, but I like to use the selectExpr:

```
.selectExpr("id", "symbol_id", // or whatever other field you like
  "explode.index as index_0",  // then target the key with dot operator
  "explode.risk_buy as risk_buy_index_0",
  "explode.reward_buy as reward_buy_index_0"
  // add your other wanted values
)
```

Dummy input:

```
+--------------------------+---+---------+
|risk_table                |id |symbol_id|
+--------------------------+---+---------+
|[{1, 0.25, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3}]|1  |1        |
+--------------------------+---+---------+
```

Final output:

```
+---+---------+-------+----------------+------------------+
| id|symbol_id|index_0|risk_buy_index_0|reward_buy_index_0|
+---+---------+-------+----------------+------------------+
|  1|        1|      1|            0.25|               0.3|
+---+---------+-------+----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, I have added a new update, I would like to convert those new records into columns appended to the original dataframe, I've added an example, thanks again for your time helping me.

Comment: What is your unique id in your second edited dataframe?

Comment: It would be element.Index, each record has a different value inside index like: "count","mean","std", "50%, and then the other attributes will keep the same, so they idea will be "count_risk_reward", "count_risk_sell","count_risk_buy", "mean_risk_reward", "mean_risk_sell", or index_0_risk_sell, index_1_risk_sell, we have others unique attributes like symbol_id and date, 

thank you for replying my comments i highly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I got it working using group by date and then pivot by the index, I added my solution into the question. 
Greetings from Colombia!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

After call the explode function from vilalabinot answer, I just had to group by date and then pivot the field of the records inside risk_table, something like this:

```
df1.groupBy(col("date")).pivot(col("index_0"))
     .agg(first(col("risk_buy_index_0")), first(col("reward_buy_index_0")))
```